# Clearing my adapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I populated a `GridView` with a Custom Adapter of images.  I added a button to sort the images.  I'm trying to figure out how to do this properly.  As of right now, I'm trying to delete all the images by using the `clear()` method and repopulating it with the sorted images.  However, I can't seem to delete the images.  It just adds to the sorted images to the original.  Please help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTextView;
    String githubSearchResults;
    String default_sort = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=(MY OWN API KEY)";
    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> posterData = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject results;
    private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.movie_image);
        getURL(default_sort);
    }

    JSONArray getResults(String JSONString) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject movieResults = new JSONObject(JSONString);
        JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)movieResults.getJSONArray("results");
        if (jArray != null) {
            for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
            }
        }
        return jArray;
    }

    void getPosterPath() throws JSONException {
        for(int i = 0;i<listdata.size();i++) {
            results = new JSONObject(listdata.get(i));
            String poster_path = results.getString("poster_path");
            posterData.add(poster_path);
            Log.d("myTag", poster_path);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sort_popular, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.popular:
                movieAdapter.clear();
                movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                String sort_popular = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=(MY OWN API KEY)";
                getURL(sort_popular);
                return true;

            default:

                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
        return true;
    }

    private void getURL(String string){
        URL getURL = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(string);
        new GithubQueryTask().execute(getURL);
    }

    public class GithubQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
        // COMPLETED (2) Override the doInBackground method to perform the query. Return the results. (Hint: You've already written the code to perform the query)

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {

            URL searchUrl = params[0];
            String githubSearchResults = null;
            try {
                githubSearchResults = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl);
                getResults(githubSearchResults);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return githubSearchResults;
        }

        // COMPLETED (3) Override onPostExecute to display the results in the TextView

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String githubSearchResults) {

            try {
                getPosterPath();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this, posterData);

            GridView listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listview_flavor);
            listView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my custom adapter:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ImageView mImageView;

    public MovieAdapter(Activity context, List<String> movieArray) {
        super(context, 0, movieArray);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String androidFlavor = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_detail, parent, false);
        }

        mImageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_image);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/"+androidFlavor).into(mImageView);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, the problem is you never clear **posterData** list (what about **listdata** as well). You just keep adding to it. I would suggest to change the **getPosterPath** method like this:

```
void getPosterPath() throws JSONException {
    posterData.Clear();
    for(int i = 0;i<listdata.size();i++) {
        results = new JSONObject(listdata.get(i));
        String poster_path = results.getString("poster_path");             
        posterData.add(poster_path);
        Log.d("myTag", poster_path);
    }
    movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in **public boolean onOptionsItemSelected** you don't need to call

```
        movieAdapter.clear();
        movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

since any change in the list the adapter is bound to should reflect in the adapter after getPosterPath() gets executed.

**EDIT:**

The reason you get this error is because

```
movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this, posterData);
```

happens after the call to getPosterPath().

Just alter the **onPostExectute()** a bit:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String githubSearchResults) {

    movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this, posterData);        

    try {
        getPosterPath();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    GridView listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listview_flavor);
    listView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);


}
```

Comment: Thanks, but these changes made my app crash with this error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.thuon.popularmovies, PID: 10504
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.thuon.popularmovies.MovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: Thanks again.  But this just gets me back to my original problem.  It is still just adding onto to original instead of deleting the original and repopulating it.